# Custom sorting by object index ArrayList containing arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an ArrayList made up of string arrays and I am trying to let my program's user do a custom sort. The string arrays are each made up of 4 strings. I would like the allow the user to select by which of these strings and in in which order he would like to sort the array list.

**Example**

*The ArrayList is made up of the following String[4]*

```
{"A", "B", "C", "D"}
{"A", "BE", "HC", "Z"}
{"U", "NN", "HC", "Y"}
```

The user can say he wants to sort the array list according to index 1 then by index 3.

Or the user can say he wants to sort by index 2,0,1,3.

How can I go about doing this?

**EDIT**

Sort by 2 then 3 would be like this

```
{"A", "B", "C", "D"}
{"U", "NN", "HC", "Y"}
{"A", "BE", "HC", "Z"}
```

Comment: I don't have a clear understanding of what *sort the array list according to index 1 then by index 3* means. Could you give example outputs for the cases you described?

Comment: added example thanks for the help!

Comment: If the user is giving you the exact order that should be sorted, plus if he gives you it by index,  why don't you create a another array and copy the elements to it according to the given order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

static void sortByIndices(List<String[]> list, int first, int... rest) {
    Comparator<String[]> comparator = comparing(array -> array[first]);
    for (int index : rest) {
        comparator = comparator.thenComparing(array -> array[index]);
    }
    list.sort(comparator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom Comparators, that allows you to pass in different indices evaluating the arrays at different positions within the String[] and reuse for each selection.

Something like this:

```
public ArrayComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
    private int[] mySortingIndices;

public ArrayComparator (final int[] theSortingIndices) {
    super();
    mySortingIndices = theSortingIndices;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(String[] this, String[] that) {
     int relPosition = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < mySortingIndices.length; i++) {
         relPosition = this[mySortingIndices[i].compareTo(that[mySortingIndices[i]);
     }
    return relPosition;
    }

}
```

And pass an instance of this comparator to Collections.sort() along with your ArrayList like this:

```
 Collections.sort(myList, new ArrayComparator <String[]>(new int[]{1, 3}));
```

Comment: This won't allow him to use multiple indices (1 and then 3) to sort as he wants.

Comment: Yip yip. Reread the question and my answer is insufficient. Thanks for the heads up @Codebender.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a case of a specific algorithm.

For one thing, you could use something like this,

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
    int[] indices;

    @Override
    public int compare(String[] thiz, String[] that) {
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            int retVal = thiz[indices[i]].compareTo(that[indices[i]]);
            if (retVal == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                return retVal;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Just make sure to assign `indices` to the required value (like `[2,0,1,3]` if you want to sort by the indices in that order), before calling `Collections.sort(list, CustomComparator)`